# Evaluating improper integrals with the help of contour integrals.

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, problem-solving, contour-integration

I am a graduate student.I have been studying complex analysis from Stein Shakarchi's book.In chapter $2$ ,there is an exercise which is as follows:
[image]

As given in the hint,I assume that the countour is $C$ and I used Cauchy's theorem,to get $\int_C e^{-z^2}dz=0$.

Now I split the integral into three parts.First one is along the line segment from $0$ to $R$ which will give me the desired integral when $R\to \infty$.But I am unable to manipulate the integral along the arc which turns out to be ,$\int_0^{\pi/4} e^{-R^2e^{2it}}.Rie^{it}dt$.Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Note that your goal is not to evaluate that integral, but show that it goes to zero as $R\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I know that,but I cannot find a suitable estimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, we want to put an uppoer bound on the magnitude of the integral. Moving the absolute value inside is a good start to get rid of annoying phase terms:
$$
\left|iR\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2e^{2it}}e^{it}dt\right|\le R\int_0^{\pi/4}\left|e^{-R^2e^{2it}}e^{it}dt\right| = R\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2\cos(2t)}dt.
$$
Next, note that $\cos(2t) \ge 1 - 4t/\pi$ on this interval, which leads to
$$
R\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2\cos(2t)}dt \le R\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2(1-4t/\pi)}dt = \frac{\pi}{4R}\left(1-e^{-R^2}\right)\le \frac{\pi}{4R}.
$$
Putting these together we have
$$
\left|iR\int_0^{\pi/4}e^{-R^2e^{2it}}e^{it}dt\right|\le \frac{\pi}{4R}
$$
and thus the integral goes to zero as $R\rightarrow\infty$.